# Finding the maximum and minimum times to melt 100g of butter.

Tags: derivatives, optimization

**The time in minutes to melt 100g of butter (t) depends upon the percentage of the butter that is made of saturated fats (p), as shown in the following fuction:$$t=\frac{p^2}{10000}+\frac{p}{100}+2$$ Find the maximum and minimum times to melt 100g of butter.**

I started by differentiating to get:$$\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{p}{5000}+\frac{1}{100}$$ I set this equal to zero to get the stationary point, but got an answer or p=-50, but that doesn’t seem right. Also this would only give one of the answers, so how would I get the other? Many thanks.

Comment: Is assumed to be $p>0$?

Comment: I guess so, the problem doesn’t specify, but I don’t think it would make sense for p to be less than zero.

Comment: @Jamminermit Since $p \gt 0$ , $f(t)$ is a monotonically increasing function.Hence min value would occur at $p=0$ and max value would occur at $p = 100$.

Comment: Ok. So for a monotonic function, the maximum and minimums occur at the endpoints? This is a new term for me, so making sure that I get this right!

Comment: This problem is for teaching you the theorem, not the other way around !!! You are supposed to figure out right away that the min is at p=0 and max at p=100 without doing any math.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that now. I think my main issue was that I wasn’t considering that p was bounded between 0 and 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let

$$\text{t = time in minutes}$$
$$\text{100g = amount of butter}$$
$$\text{p = percentage of butter that is made of saturated fats}$$

where two extremes occur when the butter has no saturated fat $(p=0)$ or the butter consists of only saturated fat $(p=100)$. Then, the total amount of time to melt all the butter is given by the function

$$t(p)=\frac{p^2}{10000}+\frac{p}{100}+2$$

As $p\ge 0$ by definition, $t(p)$ is a monotonically increasing function. Therefore, the minimum amount of time occurs when the butter contains no saturated fat. We have

$$t(0)=2$$

so the minimum occurs at $2$ minutes. On the other hand, the maximum occurs when the butter is made of $100\%$ saturated fat. Here

$$t(100)=1+1+2=4$$

so the maximum amount of time to melt all the butter is $4$ minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Since $p$ is a percentage,  $p$ should be between $0$ and $100$. In this range the function is increasing. So the minimum time is at $t(0)=2$ and the maximum time is at $t(100)=4$.